# This keeps happening - Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.resources.dll is not found during .NET Core 3.1 debug session in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-2019, .net-core-3.1, microsoft-data-sqlclient

This keeps happening - Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.resources.dll is not found during .NET Core 3.1 debug session in Visual Studio 2019

Exception message:
"Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\user1\Dev\source\repos\repo_name\project_name\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\runtimes\win\lib\netcoreapp3.1\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.resources.dll'. The system cannot find the file specified."

It is only happening with this specific package, basically when I go to create a new SqlConnection object instance. Everything is working fine, except that some random software change on the system seems to always impact this package.

I'm stumped. Any ideas how to work around this in C#? It seems like it magically fixes itself if I repair or reinstall Visual Studio and .NET Core SDKs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nuget Packages to add System.data.SqlClient:

[In the solution explorer /Dependencies/Packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzV98.png)

[Search system.Data.SqlClient and add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFReK.png)

Other investigation that could help you:https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ec2361a3-1931-4423-bf68-08b206ce67aa/reference-systemdatasqlclient-not-found?forum=netfxbcl

Comment: We are moving to use the Microsoft.Data.SqlClient since that is where .NET 5 and beyond is moving.